Pyflink unable to access State Value for a previous message with key_by
I have a pyflink application that does 3 things with an incoming message with this schema: ['KEY', 'AGG_FIELD1','AGG_FIELD2']

For each KEY, store the value of aggKey = concat(AGG_FIELD1, AGG_FIELD2) in the statestore (state1).

For each value of aggKey, append the KEY as a list of values in another statestore (state2).

When an update message comes along with the same KEY but different aggKey, detect changes by comparing the new aggKey with the current aggKey in state1. If there is a change, use the old/current aggKey as a Key to access the state in state2 and remove the KEY from the list of KEY


import argparse
import logging
import sys
import json
import os

from pyflink.common import WatermarkStrategy, Encoder, Types, Row
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment, RuntimeExecutionMode, OutputTag
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.file_system import (FileSource, StreamFormat, FileSink,
                                                       OutputFileConfig, RollingPolicy)
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import KafkaSource
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import KafkaSource, KafkaOffsetsInitializer, KafkaSink, KafkaRecordSerializationSchema, KafkaSinkBuilder
from pyflink.common.serialization import SimpleStringSchema, SerializationSchema
from pyflink.datastream.state import ValueStateDescriptor, MapStateDescriptor, ListStateDescriptor
from pyflink.datastream.functions import RuntimeContext, MapFunction, KeyedProcessFunction, FlatMapFunction, ProcessFunction
from pyflink.metrics import Counter
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowSerializationSchema, JsonRowDeserializationSchema
from pyflink.datastream.state_backend import RocksDBStateBackend
# imports for custom state data structure
from typing import List

class DetectChanges(KeyedProcessFunction):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = None

    def open(self, runtime_context: RuntimeContext):
        state_descriptor = ValueStateDescriptor("stream_key_change", Types.STRING())
        self.state = runtime_context.get_state(state_descriptor)

    def process_element(self, message, ctx: 'KeyedProcessFunction.Context'):
        key = message["KEY"]
        group_cols_fields = ['AGG_FIELD1','AGG_FIELD2']
        group_cols = [message[col] for col in group_cols_fields]

        # Access state in json format
        current_value = json.loads(self.state.value() or '{"aggKey": ""}')

        # Logic Gates
        concat_value = "-".join(group_cols) #form the aggregate key from latest message
        current_agg_key = current_value['aggKey'] #get the current aggregate key from state, if any
        agg_key_change = False

        if not current_agg_key: # first time record, current_agg_key is empty
            agg_key_change = False
            current_value['aggKey'] = concat_value        
        elif concat_value != current_agg_key:  # record has a new agg key
            agg_key_change = True
            current_value['aggKey'] = concat_value
        else:
            agg_key_change = False
            current_value['aggKey'] = concat_value  # Existing key, similar value, do nothing
        
        updated_value_json_string = json.dumps(current_value)
        
        # Update state (even if no change)
        self.state.update(updated_value_json_string)

        yield (message, agg_key_change, current_value, current_agg_key, key, concat_value)

class ProcessFunction(KeyedProcessFunction):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state1 = None
        self.agg_key_pk_list_state = None

    def open(self, runtime_context: RuntimeContext):
        state1 = ValueStateDescriptor("state1", Types.STRING())
        agg_key_pk_list_state = ListStateDescriptor("agg_key_pk_list_state", Types.STRING())
        self.state1 = runtime_context.get_state(state1)
        self.agg_key_pk_list_state = runtime_context.get_list_state(agg_key_pk_list_state)


    def process_element(self, value, ctx: 'KeyedProcessFunction.Context'):
        message = value[0]
        agg_key_change = value[1]
        old_agg_key = value[3]
        switch = message["SWITCH"]
        key = message["KEY"]
        group_cols_fields = ['AGG_FIELD1','AGG_FIELD2']
        group_cols = [message[col] for col in group_cols_fields]
        other_cols_fields = ['KEY']
        other_cols = {col: message[col] for col in other_cols_fields}
        other_cols_values = [message[col] for col in other_cols_fields]

        # Group by group_cols_fields
        concat_value = "-".join(group_cols)
    
        # Access state in json format
        state1_value = json.loads(self.state1.value() or '{"aggKey": "", "primaryKey": [], "grouped": {"aggKey": "", "nestedFields": [{"KEY": ""}]}}')

        # Logic Gates
        concat_value = "-".join(group_cols)
        current_pkey_list = state1_value['primaryKey']
        current_agg_key = state1_value['aggKey']
        current_grouped = state1_value['grouped']

        if not agg_key_change:
            if concat_value == current_agg_key and key not in current_pkey_list: #append new key to group
                state1_value['aggKey'] = concat_value
                state1_value['primaryKey'].append(key)
                state1_value['grouped']['nestedFields'].append(other_cols)
                self.agg_key_pk_list_state.add(key)
            elif concat_value == current_agg_key and key in current_pkey_list: #no change needed to state, but output new group
                state1_value['grouped']['nestedFields'].update(other_cols)
            else: #5bf does not exist, create new group
                state1_value['aggKey'] = concat_value
                state1_value['primaryKey'] = [key]
                state1_value['grouped']['5bf'] = concat_value
                # grouped_values = [{"key": key, "edeId": other_cols}]
                state1_value['grouped']['nestedFields'] = [other_cols]
                self.agg_key_pk_list_state.add(key)
        else:
            value_to_remove = key
            current_state = list(self.agg_key_pk_list_state.get())
            if value_to_remove in current_state:
                current_state.remove(value_to_remove)
            self.agg_key_pk_list_state.update(current_state)

        updated_value_json_string_agg = json.dumps(state1_value)

        self.state1.update(updated_value_json_string_agg)

        list_values = list(self.agg_key_pk_list_state.get())

        yield(current_agg_key, list_values, old_agg_key) 

    
def main():

    def show(ds, env):
        ds.print()
        env.execute()

    def print_stream_structure(element):
        print("Type:", type(element))
        print("Content:", element)
    
    def json_deserializer(message):
        return json.loads(message)

    def key_by_aggKey(message):    
        message = message[0]
        group_cols_fields = ['AGG_FIELD1','AGG_FIELD2']
        group_cols = [message[col] for col in group_cols_fields]
        key = "-".join(group_cols)
        print("Key:", key)
        return key
        # return "-".join(group_cols)

    def test(message):
        message = message[3]
        return message

    def agg_key_change_check(data):
        return [True in data[0]]

    def extract_agg_key_pk_list(value):
        current_agg_key = value[3]
        key = value[4]
        # data = {"current_agg_key": current_agg_key, "key": key}
        # return json.dumps(data)
        # return current_agg_key
        return current_agg_key, key
    
    
    # Configure logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename="flink_processing.log", level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

    # Create StreamExecutionEnvironment
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.add_jars("file:///home/.../flink-1.19.0/lib/flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar")

    earliest = True
    offset = KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest() if earliest else KafkaOffsetsInitializer.latest()

    #TODO: optimize json format for schema evolution and maintainability
    field_names = ['KEY', 'AGG_FIELD1','AGG_FIELD2']
    field_types = [Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()]
    row_type_info = Types.ROW_NAMED(field_names, field_types)
    json_format = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder().type_info(row_type_info).build()    

    kafka_source = KafkaSource.builder()\
        .set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9092")\
        .set_topics("flink-test")\
        .set_starting_offsets(offset)\
        .set_value_only_deserializer(json_format)\
        .build()

    #data stream for messages from upstream
    data_stream = env.from_source(kafka_source, WatermarkStrategy.for_monotonous_timestamps(), "Kafka Source")

    #Data stream key by KEY and store state value as aggKey to detect changes in aggKey value. Use to determine next step for key by aggKey
    key_stream = data_stream.key_by(lambda value: value[0]).process(DetectChanges())

    #Data stream for messages where current aggKey is different from previous aggKey for a given KEY
    correction_stream = key_stream.filter(lambda x: x[1] is True)#.map(lambda x: extract_agg_key_deno_list(x), output_type=Types.STRING())

    main_stream = key_stream.filter(lambda x: x[1] is False).key_by(lambda x: x[5])

    correction_keyed_stream = key_stream.filter(lambda x: x[1] is True).key_by(lambda x: x[3])

    stream1 = main_stream.process(ProcessFunction())
    stream2 = correction_keyed_stream.process(ProcessFunction())

    show(stream1, env)

    # kafka_sink = KafkaSink.builder()\
    #         .set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9092")\
    #         .set_record_serializer(
    #         KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
    #             .set_topic("flink-correction")
    #             .set_value_serialization_schema(SimpleStringSchema())
    #             .build()
    #         ) \
    #         .build()

    # Execute the program
    env.execute("Flink Kafka Group-by and State Processing")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


From the above, it seems that even with a key_by on the old/current aggKey, within the same message, the datastream is unable to access the state of an older message that has been processed.
I have tried this with MapState, ValueState and ListState as shown here. The question is if it's possible to acheive my requirements with state processing, and how else in pyflink can I acheive the requirements
